# Unable to run Map Reduce Jobs on Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm new to Hadoop. I am trying to check if my Yarn/Map Reduce is working correctly.(http://hadooptutorial.info/run-example-mapreduce-program/) I get this error message

```
http://localhost:8088/cluster/app/application_1468349436383_0001


    Application application_1468349436383_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1468349436383_0001_000002 exited with exitCode: 127
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://localhost:8088/cluster/app/application_1468349436383_0001Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1468349436383_0001_02_000001
Exit code: 127
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=127:
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 127
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
```

I'm guessing my configurations aren't correct because MapReduce dosen't even start up.

I'm really sorry if this is a trivial question. I've very new to hadoop and I couldn't find anything online to fix this.

Here are my hadoop configurations

yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>8</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Thank You so much

nodemanager log error snapshot

```
2016-07-13 10:37:42,145 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Exit code from container container_1468349436383_0001_01_000001 is : 127
2016-07-13 10:37:42,147 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Exception from container-launch with container ID: container_1468349436383_0001_01_000001 and exit code: 127
ExitCodeException exitCode=127:
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-07-13 10:37:42,149 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor: Exception from container-launch.
2016-07-13 10:37:42,149 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor: Container id: container_1468349436383_0001_01_000001
2016-07-13 10:37:42,149 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor: Exit code: 127
2016-07-13 10:37:42,150 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor: Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=127:
2016-07-13 10:37:42,150 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
2016-07-13 10:37:42,150 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
2016-07-13 10:37:42,150 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
2016-07-13 10:37:42,150 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
2016-07-13 10:37:42,150 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
2016-07-13 10:37:42,150 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
2016-07-13 10:37:42,150 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2016-07-13 10:37:42,150 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2016-07-13 10:37:42,150 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2016-07-13 10:37:42,150 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-07-13 10:37:42,150 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch: Container exited with a non-zero exit code 127
2016-07-13 10:37:42,151 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1468349436383_0001_01_000001 transitioned from RUNNING to EXITED_WITH_FAILURE
2016-07-13 10:37:42,151 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch: Cleaning up container container_1468349436383_0001_01_000001
2016-07-13 10:37:42,183 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting absolute path : /tmp/hadoop-aditghosh/nm-local-dir/usercache/aditghosh/appcache/application_1468349436383_0001/container_1468349436383_0001_01_000001
2016-07-13 10:37:42,184 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=aditghosh    OPERATION=Container Finished - Failed   TARGET=ContainerImpl    RESULT=FAILURE  DESCRIPTION=Container failed with state: EXITED_WITH_FAILURE    APPID=application_1468349436383_0001    CONTAINERID=container_1468349436383_0001_01_000001
2016-07-13 10:37:42,188 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1468349436383_0001_01_000001 transitioned from EXITED_WITH_FAILURE to DONE
2016-07-13 10:37:42,188 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Removing container_1468349436383_0001_01_000001 from application application_1468349436383_0001
2016-07-13 10:37:42,188 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: ResourceCalculatorPlugin is unavailable on this system. org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl is disabled.
2016-07-13 10:37:42,188 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event CONTAINER_STOP for appId application_1468349436383_0001
2016-07-13 10:37:43,970 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Removed completed containers from NM context: [container_1468349436383_0001_01_000001]
2016-07-13 10:37:43,981 INFO SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for appattempt_1468349436383_0001_000002 (auth:SIMPLE)
2016-07-13 10:37:43,986 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Start request for container_1468349436383_0001_02_000001 by user aditghosh
2016-07-13 10:37:43,987 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=aditghosh    IP=127.0.0.1    OPERATION=Start Container Request   TARGET=ContainerManageImpl  RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1468349436383_0001    CONTAINERID=container_1468349436383_0001_02_000001
2016-07-13 10:37:43,987 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Adding container_1468349436383_0001_02_000001 to application application_1468349436383_0001
2016-07-13 10:37:43,988 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1468349436383_0001_02_000001 transitioned from NEW to LOCALIZING
2016-07-13 10:37:43,988 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event CONTAINER_INIT for appId application_1468349436383_0001
2016-07-13 10:37:43,988 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1468349436383_0001_02_000001 transitioned from LOCALIZING to LOCALIZED
2016-07-13 10:37:44,037 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1468349436383_0001_02_000001 transitioned from LOCALIZED to RUNNING
2016-07-13 10:37:44,037 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: ResourceCalculatorPlugin is unavailable on this system. org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl is disabled.
2016-07-13 10:37:44,100 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: launchContainer: [bash, /tmp/hadoop-aditghosh/nm-local-dir/usercache/aditghosh/appcache/application_1468349436383_0001/container_1468349436383_0001_02_000001/default_container_executor.sh]
2016-07-13 10:37:44,132 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Exit code from container container_1468349436383_0001_02_000001 is : 127
2016-07-13 10:37:44,132 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Exception from container-launch with container ID: container_1468349436383_0001_02_000001 and exit code: 127
ExitCodeException exitCode=127:
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-07-13 10:37:44,132 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor: Exception from container-launch.
2016-07-13 10:37:44,132 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor: Container id: container_1468349436383_0001_02_000001
2016-07-13 10:37:44,132 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor: Exit code: 127
2016-07-13 10:37:44,132 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor: Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=127:
2016-07-13 10:37:44,132 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
2016-07-13 10:37:44,132 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
2016-07-13 10:37:44,133 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
2016-07-13 10:37:44,133 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
2016-07-13 10:37:44,133 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
2016-07-13 10:37:44,133 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
2016-07-13 10:37:44,133 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2016-07-13 10:37:44,133 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2016-07-13 10:37:44,133 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2016-07-13 10:37:44,133 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-07-13 10:37:44,133 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch: Container exited with a non-zero exit code 127
2016-07-13 10:37:44,133 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1468349436383_0001_02_000001 transitioned from RUNNING to EXITED_WITH_FAILURE
2016-07-13 10:37:44,133 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch: Cleaning up container container_1468349436383_0001_02_000001
2016-07-13 10:37:44,160 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting absolute path : /tmp/hadoop-aditghosh/nm-local-dir/usercache/aditghosh/appcache/application_1468349436383_0001/container_1468349436383_0001_02_000001
2016-07-13 10:37:44,161 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=aditghosh    OPERATION=Container Finished - Failed   TARGET=ContainerImpl    RESULT=FAILURE  DESCRIPTION=Container failed with state: EXITED_WITH_FAILURE    APPID=application_1468349436383_0001    CONTAINERID=container_1468349436383_0001_02_000001
2016-07-13 10:37:44,161 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1468349436383_0001_02_000001 transitioned from EXITED_WITH_FAILURE to DONE
2016-07-13 10:37:44,161 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Removing container_1468349436383_0001_02_000001 from application application_1468349436383_0001
2016-07-13 10:37:44,161 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: ResourceCalculatorPlugin is unavailable on this system. org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl is disabled.
2016-07-13 10:37:44,161 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event CONTAINER_STOP for appId application_1468349436383_0001
2016-07-13 10:37:45,983 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Removed completed containers from NM context: [container_1468349436383_0001_02_000001]
2016-07-13 10:37:45,987 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Application application_1468349436383_0001 transitioned from RUNNING to APPLICATION_RESOURCES_CLEANINGUP
2016-07-13 10:37:45,988 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting absolute path : /tmp/hadoop-aditghosh/nm-local-dir/usercache/aditghosh/appcache/application_1468349436383_0001
2016-07-13 10:37:45,988 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event APPLICATION_STOP for appId application_1468349436383_0001
2016-07-13 10:37:45,992 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Application application_1468349436383_0001 transitioned from APPLICATION_RESOURCES_CLEANINGUP to FINISHED
2016-07-13 10:37:45,992 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.loghandler.NonAggregatingLogHandler: Scheduling Log Deletion for application: application_1468349436383_0001, with delay of 10800 seconds
2016-07-13 13:37:46,480 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting path : /usr/local/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1468349436383_0001
2016-07-14 08:57:21,802 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Caught exception in status-updater
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Operation timed out; Host Details : local host is: "Adits-MacBook-Pro.local/127.0.0.1"; destination host is: "0.0.0.0":8031;
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:773)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1479)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.nodeHeartbeat(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.api.impl.pb.client.ResourceTrackerPBClientImpl.nodeHeartbeat(ResourceTrackerPBClientImpl.java:80)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy73.nodeHeartbeat(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl$1.run(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:596)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Operation timed out
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream$Reader.performIO(SocketInputStream.java:57)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.doIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:142)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:161)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:131)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$PingInputStream.read(Client.java:520)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveRpcResponse(Client.java:1084)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:979)
```

Resource Manager log error snapshot

```
2016-07-13 10:37:44,978 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService: Unregistering app attempt : appattempt_1468349436383_0001_000002
2016-07-13 10:37:44,978 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.AMRMTokenSecretManager: Application finished, removing password for appattempt_1468349436383_0001_000002
2016-07-13 10:37:44,978 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl: appattempt_1468349436383_0001_000002 State change from FINAL_SAVING to FAILED
2016-07-13 10:37:44,978 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: The number of failed attempts is 2. The max attempts is 2
2016-07-13 10:37:44,979 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: Updating application application_1468349436383_0001 with final state: FAILED
2016-07-13 10:37:44,987 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: application_1468349436383_0001 State change from ACCEPTED to FINAL_SAVING
2016-07-13 10:37:44,987 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStore: Updating info for app: application_1468349436383_0001
2016-07-13 10:37:44,987 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Application Attempt appattempt_1468349436383_0001_000002 is done. finalState=FAILED
2016-07-13 10:37:44,987 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.AppSchedulingInfo: Application application_1468349436383_0001 requests cleared
2016-07-13 10:37:44,988 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: Application application_1468349436383_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1468349436383_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: 127
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://localhost:8088/cluster/app/application_1468349436383_0001Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1468349436383_0001_02_000001
Exit code: 127
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=127: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 127
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
2016-07-13 10:37:44,988 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: Application removed - appId: application_1468349436383_0001 user: aditghosh queue: default #user-pending-applications: 0 #user-active-applications: 0 #queue-pending-applications: 0 #queue-active-applications: 0
2016-07-13 10:37:44,990 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: application_1468349436383_0001 State change from FINAL_SAVING to FAILED
2016-07-13 10:37:44,991 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: Application removed - appId: application_1468349436383_0001 user: aditghosh leaf-queue of parent: root #applications: 0
2016-07-13 10:37:44,992 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=aditghosh    OPERATION=Application Finished - Failed TARGET=RMAppManager RESULT=FAILURE  DESCRIPTION=App failed with state: FAILED   PERMISSIONS=Application application_1468349436383_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1468349436383_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: 127
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://localhost:8088/cluster/app/application_1468349436383_0001Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1468349436383_0001_02_000001
Exit code: 127
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=127: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 127
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.  APPID=application_1468349436383_0001
2016-07-13 10:37:44,994 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager$ApplicationSummary: appId=application_1468349436383_0001,name=QuasiMonteCarlo,user=aditghosh,queue=default,state=FAILED,trackingUrl=http://localhost:8088/cluster/app/application_1468349436383_0001,appMasterHost=N/A,startTime=1468431458818,finishTime=1468431464979,finalStatus=FAILED,memorySeconds=8214,vcoreSeconds=4,preemptedAMContainers=0,preemptedNonAMContainers=0,preemptedResources=<memory:0\, vCores:0>,applicationType=MAPREDUCE
2016-07-13 10:47:24,771 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.WebAppProxyServlet: dr.who is accessing unchecked http://localhost:8088/cluster/app/application_1468349436383_0001 which is the app master GUI of application_1468349436383_0001 owned by aditghosh
2016-07-13 11:50:38,782 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Updating the current master key for generating delegation tokens
2016-07-13 11:50:38,782 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Updating the current master key for generating delegation tokens
2016-07-13 11:50:38,792 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.RMDelegationTokenSecretManager: storing master key with keyID 3
2016-07-13 11:50:38,793 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStore: Storing RMDTMasterKey.
2016-07-14 08:56:27,045 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Socket Reader #1 for port 8031: readAndProcess from client 10.0.0.19 threw exception [java.io.IOException: Operation timed out]
java.io.IOException: Operation timed out
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.channelRead(Server.java:2603)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.access$2800(Server.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Connection.readAndProcess(Server.java:1481)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener.doRead(Server.java:771)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener$Reader.doRunLoop(Server.java:637)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener$Reader.run(Server.java:608)
2016-07-14 08:57:22,834 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceTrackerService: Received duplicate heartbeat from node localhost:53667 responseId=65089
2016-07-14 11:50:41,081 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Updating the current master key for generating delegation tokens
2016-07-14 11:50:41,081 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Updating the current master key for generating delegation tokens
2016-07-14 11:50:41,094 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.RMDelegationTokenSecretManager: storing master key with keyID 4
2016-07-14 11:50:41,096 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStore: Storing RMDTMasterKey.
```

Comment: can you check your resource and node managers logs and paste here.

Comment: Hi, I added the errors displayed on the logs

Comment: Personally, I use the Cloudera Quickstart VM. It has all you need to get quickly started with Hadoop